# ranorex: ExcelDataConnector (excel 2013)

Tags: automation, ms-office, ranorex

i'm trying to add a data source on Ranorex project, I have an error message: " Excel  is not installed. ExcelDataConnector  requires Excel to  be installed".

Someone knows how solve it?

please help.

Ranorex 4.0.4 and office 2013.

thank you for your answers.

:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following forum posts on the Ranorex website.

http://www.ranorex.com/forum/exceldataconnector-stopped-working-t4604.html

http://www.ranorex.com/forum/excel-connector-not-working-after-installing-excel-2013-t4811.html

Maybe one of them will help solving your issue.

Regards